# Why these tags are greyed out in firefox html source viewer?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

[image]

I want to use beautifulsoup to get all these red-circle-marked li tags, but I can only get the first li tag,which is `<li class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height" s...`
(When the page is loaded, there's only the first li tag, and when I click the small thumbnails, li tags are created. After I click through all the small thumbnails in the left, three li tags are created, which is

```
<li class="image item itemNo1 maintain-height" s...
<li class="image item itemNo2 maintain-height" s...
<li class="image item itemNo3 maintain-height" s...
```

so how to get these li tags?

html:

```
    <div class="a-text-center a-fixed-left-grid-col a-col-right" style="padding-left:1%;float:left;">
                <div class="a-row a-spacing-none a-grid-vertical-align a-grid-center canvas ie7-width-96" style="opacity: 1;">
                    <div id="main-image-container" class="a-dynamic-image-container" style="height: 377px;">

    <div id="video-outer-container">
        <div id="main-video-container" class="chromeful-container">
        </div>
        <div id="video-canvas-caption" class="a-row">
            <div class="a-column a-span12 a-text-center">
                <span id="videoCaption" class="a-color-secondary"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="a-hidden" id="auiImmersiveViewDiv"></div> 
<div class="variationUnavailable unavailableExp" style="display: none;">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="a-box a-alert a-alert-error" aria-live="assertive" role="alert"><div class="a-box-inner a-alert-container"><h4 class="a-alert-heading">Image Unavailable</h4><i class="a-icon a-icon-alert"></i><div class="a-alert-content">
            <span class="a-text-bold">
                Image not available for<br>Color:
                <span class="unvailableVariation"></span>
            </span>
        </div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-horizontal list maintain-height">
<li class="mainImageTemplate template"><span class="a-list-item">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
        <div class="imgTagWrapper">
            <span class="placeHolder"></span>
        </div>
    </span>
</span></li>
<li class="swatchHoverExp a-hidden maintain-height"><span class="a-list-item">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
        <div class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 377px;"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/912tYLsu2eL._SX425_.jpg" class="a-dynamic-image a-stretch-vertical" id="" style="max-height: 377px; max-width: 377px;" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/912tYLsu2eL._SL1500_.jpg" data-a-manual-replacement="true"></div>
    </span>
</span></li>
<li class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="a-list-item">
        <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
            <div id="imgTagWrapperId" class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 377px;">
                <img alt="6 Piece Hotel Luxury Soft 1800 Series Premium Bed Sheets Set, Deep Pockets, Hypoallergenic, Wrinkle &amp; Fade Resistant Bedding Set(Full, Cream)" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91RE-nL%2BcYL._SX425_.jpg" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91RE-nL%2BcYL._SL1500_.jpg" class="a-dynamic-image  a-stretch-vertical" id="landingImage" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91RE-nL%2BcYL._SX466_.jpg&quot;:[466,466],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91RE-nL%2BcYL._SY450_.jpg&quot;:[450,450],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91RE-nL%2BcYL._SX522_.jpg&quot;:[522,522],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91RE-nL%2BcYL._SY355_.jpg&quot;:[355,355],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91RE-nL%2BcYL._SX425_.jpg&quot;:[425,425]}" style="max-width: 377px; max-height: 377px;"><script type="text/javascript">if(typeof encodedImgSrc != 'undefined' && encodedImgSrc != "" && document.getElementById("landingImage")!= null){document.getElementById("landingImage").src=encodedImgSrc;};</script>
            </div>
        </span>
    </span></li><li id="noFlashContent" class="noFlash a-hidden"><span class="a-list-item">
    <hza:string id="softlines_dp_video_flash_player">
    <a class="a-link-normal" target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer">
        <hza:string id="softlines_dp_video_flash_player_text">
        <span class="swSprite s_extLink"></span>
    </hza:string></a>
</hza:string></span></li>
<li class="image item itemNo1 maintain-height" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="a-list-item">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
        <div class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 377px;">
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81pdBCFaeUL._SX425_.jpg" class="a-dynamic-image a-stretch-vertical" id="" style="max-height: 377px; max-width: 377px;" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81pdBCFaeUL._SL1500_.jpg" data-a-manual-replacement="true">
        </div>
    </span>
</span></li><li class="image item itemNo2 maintain-height selected" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="a-list-item">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
        <div class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 377px;">
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91y-xuiUG2L._SX425_.jpg" class="a-dynamic-image a-stretch-vertical" id="" style="max-height: 377px; max-width: 377px;" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91y-xuiUG2L._SL1500_.jpg" data-a-manual-replacement="true">
        </div>
    </span>
</span></li><li class="image item itemNo3 maintain-height" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="a-list-item">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
        <div class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 377px;">
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91cd38Ag0RL._SX425_.jpg" class="a-dynamic-image a-stretch-vertical" id="" style="max-height: 377px; max-width: 377px;" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91cd38Ag0RL._SL1500_.jpg" data-a-manual-replacement="true">
        </div>
    </span>
</span></li></ul>







<script type="text/javascript">
    var mainImgContainer = document.getElementById("main-image-container");

    var containerWidth = mainImgContainer.offsetWidth;
    var holderRatio = 1.0;
    var shouldAutoPlay = false;
    var containerHeight = containerWidth/holderRatio;
    containerHeight = Math.min(containerHeight, 700);

    var dynamicImageMaxHeight = 522 ;
    var dynamicImageMaxWidth = 522 ;
    var aspectRatio = dynamicImageMaxWidth/dynamicImageMaxHeight;
    var landingImage = document.getElementById("landingImage");
    var imgWrapperDiv = document.getElementById("imgTagWrapperId");

    var imageMaxHeight = containerHeight;
    var imageMaxWidth = containerWidth;

    if(!shouldAutoPlay) {
        imageMaxHeight = Math.min(imageMaxHeight, dynamicImageMaxHeight);
        imageMaxWidth = Math.min(imageMaxWidth, dynamicImageMaxWidth);
    }


    var useImageBlockLeftColCentering = false;
    var rightMargin = 32;

    if(typeof useImageBlockLeftColCentering !== "undefined" && useImageBlockLeftColCentering){
        mainImgContainer.style.marginRight = rightMargin + "px";
    }
    mainImgContainer.style.height = containerHeight + "px";

    var imageMaxWidthBasedOnHeight = imageMaxHeight * aspectRatio;
    var imageMaxHeightBasedOnWidth = imageMaxWidth / aspectRatio;
    imageMaxHeight = Math.min(imageMaxHeight, imageMaxHeightBasedOnWidth);
    imageMaxWidth = Math.min(imageMaxWidth, imageMaxWidthBasedOnHeight);

    if(imgWrapperDiv){
        imgWrapperDiv.style.height = containerHeight + "px";
    }

    if(landingImage){
        landingImage.style.maxHeight = imageMaxHeight + "px";
        landingImage.style.maxWidth = imageMaxWidth + "px";
    }

    if(shouldAutoPlay){
        if(landingImage){
            landingImage.style.height = imageMaxHeight + "px";
            landingImage.style.width  = imageMaxWidth + "px";
        }
    }

</script>






                </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px); z-index: 3; width: 48px; height: 48px; border: 8px solid rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 100%; display: none;"><span class="a-spinner a-spinner-medium"></span></div></div>

            <div id="image-canvas-caption" class="a-row">
                 <div class="a-column a-span12 a-text-center">
                    <span id="canvasCaption" class="a-color-secondary">Roll over image to zoom in</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collections-collect-button"></div>
        </div>
```

and [https://www.amazon.com/Premium-Pockets-Hypoallergenic-Wrinkle-Resistant/dp/B079S9XHMG/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?s=bedbath&ie=UTF8&qid=1522410001&sr=1-1-spons&keywords=sheets&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079S9XHMG) is the web link I used to analylize.

Comment: Hello, simply because they are not displayed. `display: none;`

Comment: If I want to get all these tags in beautifulsoup, what should I do? HELP! @Kangouroops

Comment: imageItem = soup.find_all(class_=re.compile(r'itemNo\b+')) can only get the first li tag that is <li class="image item itemNo0 maintain-height" s... @Kangouroops

Comment: Sorry, I've never used beautifulsoup.

Comment: Is your question resolved? Update the question with the exact _UseCase_ you are trying to Automate along with the relevant _HTML_ and your code trials.

Comment: updated @DebanjanB